# Running native code with CreateRemoteThread

Tags: c++, winapi, mono

A bit of background, this is my first ever question on stack overflow, so if it is difficult to answer, because of the quality of my question, I'm sorry.

Running on: Windows 11 10.0.22000 Build 22000, Intel x64, C++20, Mono 4.5, Visual Studio 2022 (if you need to know something else, then ask)

I have been struggling on this problem for a few days. I've been using the C++ Mono API to try to inject a method from a C# Class Library (DLL) into another process. It's been going great for a while now, I've managed to get the MonoMethod object from the method I want to inject, and I have found multiple ways of executing it, such as:

`mono_runtime_invoke(MonoMethod *method, void *obj, void **params, MonoObject **exc)`

`mono_method_get_unmanaged_thunk(MonoMethod* method)` (which returns a C/C++ function  pointer)

`mono_compile_method(MonoMethod* method)` (I will come back to this in a moment)

but the problem is, that none of these have let me execute it remotely. I think the best shot I have with is the
`mono_compile_method(MonoMethod* method)`, since the documentation tells me `This JIT-compiles the method, and returns the pointer to the native code produced.`

The Docs: http://docs.go-mono.com/

mono_runtime_invoke and mono_method_get_unmanaged_thunk: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=xhtml%3Adeploy%2Fmono-api-methods.html (scroll down)

mono_compile_method is in the 'Unsorted' section in the left.

I thought I could just allocate some memory in the target process using `VirtualAllocEx` and `WriteProcessMemory` to somehow put the code inside the target program's address space and then execute it using `CreateRemoteThread`.

The `VirtualAllocEx` and `WriteProcessMemory` always succeed, same as the `CreateRemoteThread`, no errors are thrown, but it's only ever done one thing, which is crash the target process due to *Access Violation*.

This is my attempt (injection code):

```
MonoAssembly* Manager::Inject(const char* dllpath, char *ass, UINT len)
{

    MonoClass* classs;
    MonoMethod* method;

    MonoDomain* domain = mono_jit_init("ass");

    
    MonoAssembly* asse = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, dllpath);
    if (!asse)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open assembly.";
        return NULL;
    }

    MonoImage* monoImage = mono_assembly_get_image(asse);
    if (!monoImage)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get image from assembly.";
        return NULL;
    }
    classs = mono_class_from_name(monoImage, this->namespaceName.c_str(), this->className.c_str());
    if (!classs)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get class from name.";
        return NULL;
    }
    
    method = mono_class_get_method_from_name(classs, this->method.c_str(), -1);
    if (!method)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get method from name.";
        return NULL;
    }

    
    MonoObject* excPtr = nullptr;

    int size = 1024 * 8;
    void* code;
    code = mono_compile_method(method);

    if (handle)
    {

        void* loc = VirtualAllocEx(handle, NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        

        if (!loc)
        {
            std::cout << "VirtualAllocEx failed # " << GetLastError();
            return NULL;
        }


        SIZE_T written = 0;


        if (!WriteProcessMemory(handle, loc, code, size, &written))
        {
            std::cout << "WriteProcessMemory failed # " << GetLastError();
            return NULL;
        }
        std::cout << written << " bytes written.\n";


        HANDLE h = CreateRemoteThread(handle, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loc, NULL, 0, NULL);

        if (!h)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to create remote thread # " << GetLastError();
            return NULL;
        }


        DWORD waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(h, -1);

        if (waitResult == WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to wait for remote thread. # " << GetLastError();
            return NULL;
        }


        DWORD error;

        if (!GetExitCodeThread(h, &error))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to get thread exit code. # " << GetLastError();
            return NULL;
        }


        if (error == 3221225477)
        {
            std::cout << "An access violation occurred while executing.";
            return NULL;
        }


    } 
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid handle! # " << GetLastError();
        return NULL;
    }
        


    CloseHandle(handle);
    return asse;

}
```

This is my Dll which contains the method which will be injected:

```
using System;

namespace TestDll
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static void PrintText()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HELLO FROM DLL");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for my test target application:

```
using System;

namespace TestTarget
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "";
            while(true)
            {
                s = Console.ReadLine();
                if(s == "stop")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the message TestTarget throws when I try to inject:

```
The program '[9636] TestTarget.exe' has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I know the mono_compile_method works, because if I try to cast the return value to a function pointer and call it:

```
void (*code)() = (void(*)())mono_compile_method(method);
code();
```

It works as expected, and prints

```
HELLO FROM DLL
```

So, it says it returns a pointer to native code (which if I'm right should be directly executable by the CPU). I'm wondering why won't it work when I use it on CreateRemoteThread, since I can call it as a function pointer. I think I am calling it wrong/I wrote the pointer to the native code to the memory, which points to the native code in my process, but god knows what in the target process, since processes have their own address spaces.

If what I'm trying to do (inject the method into a remote process) is not possible like this, then please try and supply a corresponding technique. Thanks, if you have any questions about my question (:D), then please ask.

Comment: `code` must be base independed code without imports.

Comment: It's probably far easier to decompile the .NET code and re-write it in C. The number of C compilers that can emit free-standing PIC (position independent code) is non-zero. I'm not sure this is true for any CLR implementation (outside of theory).

Comment: @RbMm I'm not sure what you mean. Would be great if you could submit an answer to explain in more detail!

Comment: @IInspectable Do you know how to do that if I have the C-style function pointer for the injectable method received from mono_method_get_unmanaged_thunk? If so, could you post an answer to explain in more detalji?

Comment: This is likely a topic that can easily fill books. As it stands your C# code has dependencies on the [`System.Console`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console) type, the BCL (to support the `string` type), which in turn relies on .NET's allocator. You would need to get rid of all of those, and then solve the issue of emitting position independent code. That's a *lot* of effort, and far easier done in C (or Rust, if you're adventurous). And even then writing proper shell code is difficult in itself.

Comment: @epicMan123 *I'm not sure what you mean.* - in this case you try do things, what is beyond your current knowledge

Comment: @RbMm I know it is, that's why I'm trying to learn.

Comment: If you want to learn, take out the .NET/CLR dependency. All it does is complicate things beyond hope of making any forward progress. Instead, write some shell code in assembly (x86 is probably easier than x64), copy that into a target process, and run it by creating a remote thread. Once you have a firm grasp on this you could consider writing your shell code in C. After you've mastered that you're probably going to ditch the idea of running .NET code in a foreign process, even when it is [AOT-compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation).

Answer (score -2):

You need to write injected data and code(not function pointer as you pointed) to the remote process. [There is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175354/15511041) of *Three Ways to Inject*. Be noticed *The CreateRemoteThread & WriteProcessMemory Technique*.

Comment: I've read the article two times now, but I haven't found the solution to the main problem - which is how can I write a copy of the desired function to memory? Either using the function pointer or the 'native code' produced by mono_compile_method.

Comment: The linked example writes the size `int cbCodeSize = (PBYTE) AfterThreadFunc - (PBYTE) ThreadFunc` content beginning at `ThreadFunc`(code data) to remote process.

Comment: The comments on the question are *way* more useful than this proposed answer. As it stands, it avoids answering the question altogether.